# CSOM retrieve List Item doesn't show some Lookup Key Value pairs

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, column, client-object-model, list-item

I try to load a `ListItemCollection` from my `SiteCollection` using `CSOM C#`.

Therefore I use the following

```
List rr = web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyTitle");
context.Load(rr);

FieldCollection fcol = rr.Fields;
context.Load(fcol);

ListItemCollection rrCol = rr.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
context.Load(rrCol);

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Alright, so I'm retrieving a `FieldCollection` (this is jsut for me, to check what Column Names I have in the `List`) and I retrieve a `ListItemCollection`. I can see all `ListItem`s I expect in the Collection, which is good.

But my problem is, some Values are not listed in the `ListItem`.

I want to read some `FieldLookupValue`s. So normally I can go and write something like

```
 FieldLookupValue val1 = ((FieldLookupValue) item["lookupColumn"]);
 int id1 = val1.LookupId;
```

and for most of my `LookupValue`s in the `ListItem` I can do that. But some of the Columnnames aren't listed.

I can't see some `Lookups` in the `List`, but some I can see. Whay could that be? 
When I take a look into the `FieldCollection` I can see there are 100 Fields in the `List`. But when I look into the `ListItem` I only see 77 Columnnames.

Comment: If your problem is only related to lookup fields, try to load one list referred by a lookup column and see if the field loads.

Comment: Doesn't work :(

Comment: Is the problem only related to lookup fields ?

Comment: Check the field names, on SharePoint go to the list paramaters, go into field values, and click on the fields you can't get. In the url, you can see the internal name. It's only a supposition, and if it's correct we'll dig further

Comment: I'm using the internal name. I can see the correct name of the column in the FieldCollection. But it's not listed in the Item itself. Though it has a value, when I use the browser to look into the Site Collection and view the List.

Comment: I've got 2 more questions for you : what is the type of field you can't get ? any or particular types (urls, datetime, user, ...) ? And does the internal name contain some special characters or spaces ?

Comment: I have the exact same problem: I created a Site Column as a Lookup value to a specific list.  Then I used it in 2 Site Content Types.  I applied one content type to a list, and the other to a different list. When I query both lists via CSOM and get a list item, I see the lookup value field in one of the lists, but not the other list. The lookup value field is not included in FieldValues of the 2nd list, and if I try to use the "indexer" syntax to access the field (e.g. item["fieldName"]), I get a PropertyOrFieldNotInitizalizedException.  It is VERY odd.  Let me know if you resolved your issue.

Comment: Update:  I think the issue may be related to the fact that the Lookup field is a Site Column, no just a column directly added to the list.  I still don't know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Yet another update: my site column (see prev comment) is defined in a parent site (root web), and the library that I am using it in is 2 levels down.  When I try to add a stand alone new column to that list, of type lookup, it only allows me to select from lists on that site, not parent sites.  I think the CSOM is not getting that site column field value in the query because the client context is for a sub-sub-site.  Not sure how to fix this....perhaps I'll need to query using a parent context?